# Knockout.js mapping from js and template usage

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

the main concept is following - we have main state object which contains of sections and every section have it's own data and type. I want to display every section data based on section type. The main object looks like this:

```
var data = {
  state: {
    sections: [{
      section: {
        Id: "1",
        Type: "Text",
        Version: 2,
        Data: ["one", "two"]
      }
    }, {
      section: {
        Id: "2",
        Type: "Text",
        Version: 1,
        Data: ["one", "two"]
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

I'm trying to do this with knockout mapping and templates for each section type, but don't really know how to do that. All that I have is this - https://jsfiddle.net/7hd8zed5/1/ . Any suggestions how to make this?

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically choose the name of a template by providing a method that takes the current item of the `foreach` loop and returns a template name string. ([official documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html#note-5-dynamically-choosing-which-template-is-used))

Here's an example of a 'template provider method' in your code:

**Updated data-bind**:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: getTemplateForSection, foreach: sections, as: 'obj' }"></ul>
```

**Updated StateModel:**

```
function StateModel(data) {
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping, this);

  this.getTemplateForSection = function(sectionModel) {
    var section = sectionModel.section;

    switch (section.Type()) {
      case "Text":
        return "Text-template";
      default:
        return "Error-template";
    }
  }
};
```

I've forked your fiddle and included the example I propose [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kfyzp7f7/).